# SQL query to get customers yearly net amount and Year to Year growth percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

Here is the scenario,

I am creating a report where, for each customer yearly ordered amount will be shown. And than the growth percentage comparing the previous years.

What I have tried so far :

```
    SELECT * FROM (select MrCode MrCode17,MrName MrName17, SUM(NetAmt) NetAmount17,SUM(TotalNetAmt) TotalNetAmount17 from TASKORDER_REGISTER where UCODE = 'SR01'
AND TaskOrder_Dt between '2017-1-1 00:00:00' and '2017-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MrCode,MrName) as abc 

FULL JOIN 
(select MrCode MrCode16,MrName MrName16, SUM(NetAmt) NetAmount16,SUM(TotalNetAmt) TotalNetAmount16 from TASKORDER_REGISTER where UCODE = 'SR01'
AND TaskOrder_Dt between '2016-1-1 00:00:00' and '2016-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MrCode,MrName) AS bbb
ON abc.MrCode17 = bbb.MrCode16

FULL JOIN 
(select MrCode MrCode15,MrName MrName15, SUM(NetAmt) NetAmount15,SUM(TotalNetAmt) TotalNetAmount15 from TASKORDER_REGISTER where UCODE = 'SR01'
AND TaskOrder_Dt between '2015-1-1 00:00:00' and '2015-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MrCode,MrName) AS ccc
ON bbb.MrCode16 = ccc.MrCode15
```

What is the result :

[image]

I am not sure what is the best procedure to accmplish the task. There must sume better queries to get data. And I could not create the growth percentage yet.

Comment: edit the question add sample data with tabular format rather than inline images.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following query it will return Year,Difference and [Difference Precantage].

Please add other columns in result set

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SalesData') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #SalesData END
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FinalData') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #FinalData END

    SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS ID_Num ,year(TaskOrder_Dt) SalesYear,SUM(NetAmt) TotalAmount
    INTO    #SalesData
    FROM    TASKORDER_REGISTER GROUP BY year(TaskOrder_Dt)

    SELECT
       [current].ID_Num,
       [current].TotalAmount,
       [current].SalesYear,
       [current].TotalAmount - ISNULL([next].TotalAmount, 0) AS Diff,
       (([current].TotalAmount - ISNULL([next].TotalAmount,0)) * ISNULL([next].TotalAmount,1)) * 100 AS Diffper 
       INTO #FinalData
    FROM    #SalesData       AS [current]
    LEFT JOIN   #SalesData       AS [next]
          ON [next].ID_Num = (SELECT MAX(ID_Num) FROM #SalesData WHERE ID_Num < [current].ID_Num)

    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(SalesYear) FROM #FinalData FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

    SELECT @query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT [SalesYear],Diff,Diffper FROM #FinalData) X
    PIVOT (AVG(Diff) for [SalesYear] in (' + @cols + ')) P'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Error occuring : `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type money.`

Comment: Please add script of table structure and some data too is possible.